# Google closure compiler: How to do inheritance when using a factory

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

Say I have a class Car.

```
/**
 *
 * @constructor
 * @extends {Component}
 */
obj.Car = function(prop1, prop2) {
    goog.base(this, prop1);

    this.prop2 = prop2;
};

goog.inherits(obj.Car, Component);

/**
 * 
 * @return {obj.Car}
 */
obj.Car.create = function(a,b,c) {
    var prop1 = obj.Car.createProp1(a,b,c);
    var prop2 = obj.Car.createProp2(a,b,c);
    return new obj.Car(prop1, prop2);
 }
```

Cool. Now I want to sublcass car. Call it SuperCar.

```
obj.SuperCar = function(prop1,prop2) {
    goog.base(this, prop1, prop2);
};
goog.inherits(obj.SuperCar, obj.Car);
```

How do I write the factory create method for SuperCar so that another class can also extend SuperCar?

So, ideally:

```
/**
 * @return {obj.SuperCar} 
 */
obj.SuperCar.create() = function() {
    return /** type {obj.SuperCar} */ Obj.Car.create.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

However, this means I have to change obj.Car to:

```
/**
 * @this {*) ????????? only this works
 * @return {obj.Car}
 */
obj.Car.create = function(a,b,c) {
    var prop1 = obj.Car.createProp1(a,b,c);
    var prop2 = obj.Car.createProp2(a,b,c);
    return new this(prop1, prop2);
};
```

This Javascript actually runs uncompiled and compiles. But I get a TypeError when running it compiled. Does anyone know the best solution for this? I've tried a few thing but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Where do you get the TypeError in the compiled code?  Can you post the compiled code too?   I've had CC do funny things to good code before. What optimization-level are you using?

Comment: TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.a.Ih (module_core.js:150:290)
    at Object.a.Yh (module_core.js:159:360)
    at Object.a.bi (module_core.js:161:66)
    at module_core.js:393:155
    at t.uB (module_core.js:56:348)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (module_core.js:414:412)
    at l

Comment: It doesn't like new this(). That's where the error is coming from.

Comment: This isn't a compiler issue - you aren't chaining your factory methods together in such a way that inheritance is honored. No matter how you annotate it, as written `obj.SuperCar.create` returns an `obj.Car` instance. You aren't using the `this` keyword in `obj.Car.create`, so calling it with `.apply` does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that this is the base class.

SuperCar.js

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
obj.SuperCar = function() {
};

/**
 * @return {obj.SuperCar}
 */
obj.SuperCar.create = function() {
   return new obj.SuperCar();
}
```

Car.js

```
/**
 * @param {*} prop1
 * @constructor
 * @extends {obj.SuperCar}
 */
obj.Car = function(prop1) {
    goog.base(this);

    this.prop1 = prop1;
};
goog.inherits(obj.Car, obj.SuperCar);

/**
 * @param {*} prop1
 * @return {obj.Car}
 * @override
 */
obj.SuperCar.create = function(prop1) {
   return new obj.Car(prop1);
}
```

Normally if you are going to override a function you can use `/** @inheritDoc */` annotation or if you are going to change the function definition then write the new function definition and add the `@override` annotation.